# PHP, MYSQl copy one database tables to others and replace empty with null

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am copying one complete database to other database. Every thing is working except one problem. Say one of my table has following structure

```
 id -> Integer PK AI
 state_id -> Integer (Default NULL)
 sell_id  -> Integer (Default NULL)
```

Now this table can have NULL in state_id and sell_id. So I query SELECT to this table, an empty string is return against all NULL values. But when I try to insert these values to other database table, it generates error as empty string cannot be given in integer column. Like select query return data some thing like following array

```
array(
  'id' => 1,
  'state_id' => '',
  'sell_id' => ''
)
```

So I will try to insert this array into new table, it will generate error. So I want to replace all  `''` with `NULL`. I have tried following by setting NULL to all empty values

```
  $array = array_map(function($v){
                    return $v == '' ? NULL : $v;
                },$array);
```

But this also prints `''` to all `NULL` values. This is my complete Code

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection1, "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $sortedBy DESC limit $noOfRecords");

$columns = '';
$values = '';
if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
        $array = array_values($row);
        $array = array_map(function($v){
            return $v == '' ? NULL : $v;
        },$array);

        $columns = " (".implode(", ",array_keys($row)).") ";
        $values .= " ('".implode("', '",$array)."'),";
    }
    $values = rtrim($values, ",");
    mysqli_query($dbConnection2, "INSERT INTO $table $columns VALUES $values");
}
```

But this code isn't working for above stated scenario. The Insert query is printed as

```
 INSERT INTO table (id, state_id, sell_id) VALUES (1, '', '') , (2, '', '')
```

But I want it to be like

```
 INSERT INTO table (id, state_id, sell_id) VALUES (1, NULL, NULL) , (2, NULL, NULL)
```

Can any body let me know how can I achieve that in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This could easily be done with a single query:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (newfield1, newfield2, etc...)
    SELECT oldfield1, IF(oldfield2="", NULL, oldfield2), etc...
    FROM oldtable
```

The `select` can correct/adjust any of the field values on-the-fly.

And note that your version is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Doesn't matter that the data you're dealing with came out of the database just milliseconds before - it's still unquoted/unescaped data and can/will blow up your insert query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its very large database and I don't know exact column names of each table. So I cannot put check of `IF(oldfield2="", NULL, oldfield2)` for each column and don't know about columns. And it is general script that will be run on any database. So any other solution?

Comment: And I need to run this script for millions of records of each table and there are almost 150 to 170 tables so one million time insert query will be disaster from performance point of view. I am trying to reduce time with one insert query for each table by values (), (), (). So this cannot be achieved as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

First of all if i need to move some data i do this over only SQL like @MarcB mentioned his answer but if you insist on your method i think you need to change the following line

```
return $v == '' ? NULL : $v;
```

to

```
return $v == '' ? 'NULL' : $v;
```

With this change your array's null elements becomes php's string 'NULL' so when they implode they wont convert to '' empty string they will still remains as a string NULL so they will appear as NULL in your insert SQL

Comment: `'NULL'` will become string dear :)

Comment: Can you try with this implode code:
`$a = array(1,2,3,"Null","Null");`
`echo implode(",", $a);`if you dont use `'` in implode glue it will fix it